# Create a partial template specialization throws an error

Tags: c++, templates

I have a sample class where I need to specialize the Print function if the class is of certain type.
But this doesn't compile at all.

```
template <typename classType, int size>
class MyVector
    {
    public:
        classType* innerArray;
        MyVector(){innerArray = new classType[size];}
        ~MyVector(){delete[] innerArray;}

        void push_back(classType val)
            {
            innerArray[0] = val;
            }

        classType& operator[](int index)
            {
            assert(index >= 0);
            return innerArray[index];
            }

        void Print() {
            cout << "Printing Normal" << endl;
            }
    };

void MyVector<double>::Print()
    {
    cout << "Printing Double" << endl;
    }
```

Comment: Please attach a copy of the compilation error to the question.

Comment: @Michael It says "Build Failed". Is this what you want???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MyVector` needs 2 template parameters, e.g.

```
void MyVector<double, 16>::Print()
    {
    cout << "Printing Double" << endl;
    }
```

or else you need to provide a default value for the second template parameter:

```
template <typename classType, int size = 16>
class MyVector
...
```

Comment: An unrelated question, do I need to add the MyVector<classtype, size> for each member methods that I define outside the class? For example, how would you define a normal Print() function outside the class?

Comment: @kunj2aan If you're not specialising the function, then you'd just do `template <typename classType, int size> void MyVector<classType, size>::Print() { ...`